# I want to quick vacation in a country, and then fly to another for a longer stay

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, spain, covid-19

I'm looking to travel from Bulgaria to Spain for a vacation (into smoking clubs obviously) and after my relax period of 2/3 days I would like to travel to my family in Italy for a longer stay.

Will I be stuck in Spain for a self quarantine time without the possibility to leave after 2/3 days? Can I travel to Spain and immediately after 2/3 days leave for Italy?

Answer (score 1):

As Bulgaria is in the EU, you won't need to self-quarantine but you will be subject to screening on-arrival.

From the [UK GOV Spain Travel Advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/spain/entry-requirements):

> Restrictions on travellers from outside the European Union and the Schengen free-travel area will be lifted from 1 July, providing the countries they depart from have agreements with Spain.
>
> ### Testing/screening on arrival
>
> [...]
>
> - Provide the Spanish Ministry of Health with contact information and any history of exposure to COVID-19, 48 hours prior to travel. You can do this on the [Spain Travel Health website or downloadable app](https://www.spth.gob.es/). It is mandatory for all passengers travelling to Spain to fill out and sign the online form associated with your trip, regardless of your nationality or residency status. On completion, you will be issued a personal and non-transferable QR code which you must show (electronically or hardcopy) at airport health controls on arrival
> - Temperature check
> - Undergo a visual health assessment

Comment: Hi thanks daniil, I will compile the form, You actually saved me because I wasn't going to monitor stackexchange anymore and had already booked the flight.. everything is so confusing, why they don't add it as a step when booking the tickets? they can't add such a simple necessary step but they can try to sell you the seat 591203025918 times, so ashamed, but thanks fam literally saved mine and friend's of mine's journey